# Synchronous detector question

Tags: synchronous, demodulation

[image]

The author explains it as a synchronous demodulator. Here we can see that two multipliers which multiply both the inverted and non inverted signals.

Can I do the same with only one switch for non inverted signal?

Circuit shown here is from a lock in amplifier milliohm meter.
5 V pulses are coming from the reference oscillator.
1.8 V pulses are input signal coming from a preamp that amplifies drop across a milliohm resistance.
Here is the link http://cappels.org/dproj/dlmom/dlmom.html

Comment: They are not multipliers - they are analogue switches or transmission gates à la CD4066.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You'd have to multiply your results with two.

But, you're multiplying with an on/off sequence in that case, and thus you'd obviously lose all info on the negative cycle of your input signal, and atop of that, reduce the amount of signal energy that reaches the integrator by a factor of two.

That reduces your SNR. And since you're building a lock-in amplifier, that's the worst you can do.

So, analog switches are cheap, and easy to acquire. Don't skip on them. In fact, the part that the author is using comes with **four** switches in one package, it's unclear why you'd want to use only one of them.

Comment: Also is there a half wave and full wave synchronous detector? I read something like  half wave and full wave sampling of the detector output some where in the same site.

Comment: the original circuit is a full wave detector. When you only rectify half of the waveform, like you proposed, yes, that'd be a half-wave detector. Again, not clear why you'd want to build one. It's a solution that you'd never pick under these constraints (low bandwidth, low power, high-fidelity measurements).

Comment: No I am just exploring the possibility of reducing the part count. I am learning about synchronous detectors because I am trying to build an impedance analyser.

Comment: yeah, as I said, you're not reducing the part count. The switches you get often come in multi-switch packages, and if you were to integrate that into your own IC, having another switch would be the easiest part of the job. You're looking at the wrong end of complexity.